# How to fetch relational data in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach, fetch

I need to fetch two relational tables with `foreach` method in CodeIgniter. This only an example codes I provide in my question, I will surely need this for my future projects and I'm totally blank about what kind of query to do this.

Here is **buyer** table:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Jane |
+----+------+
```

Here is **goods** table:

```
 +----+----------+------------+
 | id | buyer_id | goods_name |
 +----+----------+------------+
 |  1 |        1 | Apple      |
 |  2 |        1 | Grape      |
 |  3 |        1 | Banana     |
 |  4 |        2 | Pear       |
 |  5 |        2 | Mango      |
 +----+----------+------------+
```

In my model file **mtest**:

```
public function buyer_list()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('buyer');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}


public function order_list()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('goods');
    $this->db->join('buyer', 'buyer.id = goods.buyer_id', 'inner');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

In my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('mtest');

    $data['buyer']  =   $this->mtest->buyer_list();
    $data['order']  =   $this->mtest->order_list();

    $this->load->view('example', $data);
}
```

In my view file **example**:

```
<div id="container">
   <?php foreach ($buyer as $buyer_list): ?>
    <strong><?php echo $buyer_list->name ?></strong>: 
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($order as $order_list): ?>
        <li><?php echo $order_list->goods_name ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

That codes above only showed me the entire row of **goods** table. I want a result of something like this:

```
  +------+------------+
  | John | : • Apple  |
  |      |   • Grape  |
  +      +   • Banana +
  |      |            |
  + Jane + : • Pear   +
  |      |   • Mango  |
  +------+------------+
```

Sorry for my bad english. Any ideas?

Comment: In your `foreach` loops you are overwriting the variables.

Comment: You already have the `buyers` in the `order` because you joined the tables so there is no need to call `buyer_list()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller do this:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('mtest');

    $orders  =   $this->mtest->order_list();


    $sortedOrders = [];
    foreach($orders as $order){
        $sortedOrders[$order->name][] = $order;
    }

    $this->load->view('example', [ "sortedOrders" => $sortedOrders ]);
}
```

In view:

```
<div id="container">
   <?php foreach ($sortedOrders as $k=>$sortedOrder): ?>
    <strong><?php echo $k ?></strong>: 
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($sortedOrder as $goods): ?>
        <li><?php echo $goods->goods_name ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks sir, it works! But can u explain the function of each codes in your answer? I'm a noob

Comment: Put a `var_dump($sortedOrders);` to see how the nested array looks.

Comment: You better to make changes and see changes in a browser as output. In this way, you will learn automatically